# Is it possible to have a session recorded programmatically in Adobe Connect Pro?

Tags: adobe-connect

I need to show a link to a session recording after the session is over. But this should be handled programmatically rather than clicking on session recording by the session creator while being on session. I have read something about forced recordings, but I am unable to get it working. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to discern exactly what you're asking for. I read it as this: you need to discover the URL of your recording and include that URL in some content you're presenting.

This can be done programmatically with the Connect API:

1. Execute API action `sco-contents`

   - Include a `sco-id` parameter set to the meeting room's SCO ID.
   - Include parameter `filter-icon=archive` to limit the results to recordings
2. Walk the XML results. This XPath: `//sco[@icon='archive']` will select recordings (recordings are also referred to as archives in Connect.)
3. Select the recording of interest according to your criteria (e.g. most recent) and extract the URL from the entry.

   - Each recording will be a `<sco>` element in the results
   - The URL path will be defined in a child `<url-path>` element.
   - Append the URL path to the FQDN of your Connect service to construct the full URL.
4. Insert URL into your content.